# malloc error mmap(size=1414000640) failed (error code=12)

Tags: malloc, simulation

I am running a python script and I have the following error.

Python(13548,0xac834a28) malloc: *** mmap(size=1414000640) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Has anybody dealt with that before?
Please let me know.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: That's an out of memory error. 1.4G is a big chunk, do you have that much memory available?

Comment: I know that it is a memory error but I am not sure how to check and solve it

Comment: The general answer to that would be: by using less memory (or purchasing more RAM). You need to provide (much) more details as to what your code is, and what's it doing when that error happens if you want actual help.

Comment: I am doing a simulation with 500 chromosomes but throughout the simulation, I don't save any data. My computer is 8G RAM. It is surprising that it is not enough. Is there any actual solution to that or the only one is to try in a computer with bigger memory?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain _in detail_ your situation. (Also include whether your python interpreter is 64bit or 32bit.) We have no idea what your simulation does, what your datastructures are like, what algorithm you're using, what libraries, etc. Add the `python` tag too please, that should have been there from the start.

Comment: I run it in a computer with bigger memory and I didn't have any more this problem.